# PHP: Как получить код символа в Юникоде

Tags: php, unicode

`Например: И => u0418
          А => u0410
Какой функцией можно такое сделать?`

Answer (score 4):

В юникоде "И" будет "1048", а "А" - "1040", откуда вы взяли эти коды?

Вот рабочая функция преобразования (взято с php.net):

```
function uniord($ch) {

     $n = ord($ch{0});

     if ($n < 128) { 
         return $n; // no conversion required 
     }

     if ($n < 192 || $n > 253) { 
         return false; // bad first byte || out of range 
     }

     $arr = array(1 => 192, // byte position => range from 
                  2 => 224, 
                  3 => 240, 
                  4 => 248, 
                  5 => 252, 
                  );

     foreach ($arr as $key => $val) { 
         if ($n >= $val) { // add byte to the 'char' array 
             $char[] = ord($ch{$key}) - 128; 
             $range  = $val; 
         } else { 
             break; // save some e-trees 
         } 
     }

     $retval = ($n - $range) * pow(64, sizeof($char));

     foreach ($char as $key => $val) { 
         $pow = sizeof($char) - ($key + 1); // invert key 
         $retval += $val * pow(64, $pow);   // dark magic 
     }

     return $retval; 
}
```

Comment: Автор указал коды в 16-ричной системе

Comment: Очень странный код. Для символов ё,Ё,ю,Я в cp-1251 выполняется **return false**.

Десятичные коды CP1251  А: 192 ...  э: 253   ю: 254   я: 255   ё: 184   Ё: 168

Comment: так это 1251, а надо юникод

Comment: Насколько я понял, параметр функции uniord($ch) это символ в cp1251, а ее результат - символ в Юникоде. Разве не так ?

Comment: ну и что с того, возвращает в юникоде, все верно. а при чем твои коды в cp1251?

Comment: Не понимаю, символы **из какой кодировки** переводятся в Юникод ? Судя по тексту программы предполагаются русские символы в кодировке CP1251 (ее же иногда называют ANSI или windows, ну есть еще несколько синонимов).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
 function jdecoder($json_str) {
     $cyr_chars = array (
         '\u0430' => 'а', '\u0410' => 'А',
         '\u0431' => 'б', '\u0411' => 'Б',
         '\u0432' => 'в', '\u0412' => 'В',
         '\u0433' => 'г', '\u0413' => 'Г',
         '\u0434' => 'д', '\u0414' => 'Д',
         '\u0435' => 'е', '\u0415' => 'Е',
         '\u0451' => 'ё', '\u0401' => 'Ё',
         '\u0436' => 'ж', '\u0416' => 'Ж',
         '\u0437' => 'з', '\u0417' => 'З',
         '\u0438' => 'и', '\u0418' => 'И',
         '\u0439' => 'й', '\u0419' => 'Й',
         '\u043a' => 'к', '\u041a' => 'К',
         '\u043b' => 'л', '\u041b' => 'Л',
         '\u043c' => 'м', '\u041c' => 'М',
         '\u043d' => 'н', '\u041d' => 'Н',
         '\u043e' => 'о', '\u041e' => 'О',
         '\u043f' => 'п', '\u041f' => 'П',
         '\u0440' => 'р', '\u0420' => 'Р',
         '\u0441' => 'с', '\u0421' => 'С',
         '\u0442' => 'т', '\u0422' => 'Т',
         '\u0443' => 'у', '\u0423' => 'У',
         '\u0444' => 'ф', '\u0424' => 'Ф',
         '\u0445' => 'х', '\u0425' => 'Х',
         '\u0446' => 'ц', '\u0426' => 'Ц',
         '\u0447' => 'ч', '\u0427' => 'Ч',
         '\u0448' => 'ш', '\u0428' => 'Ш',
         '\u0449' => 'щ', '\u0429' => 'Щ',
         '\u044a' => 'ъ', '\u042a' => 'Ъ',
         '\u044b' => 'ы', '\u042b' => 'Ы',
         '\u044c' => 'ь', '\u042c' => 'Ь',
         '\u044d' => 'э', '\u042d' => 'Э',
         '\u044e' => 'ю', '\u042e' => 'Ю',
         '\u044f' => 'я', '\u042f' => 'Я',

         '\r' => '',
         '\n' => '<br />',
         '\t' => ''
     );

     foreach ($cyr_chars as $key => $value) {
         $json_str = str_replace($key, $value, $json_str);
     }
     return $json_str;
 }

 echo jdecoder("\u0421\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c"); 
?>
```

Енкодер (две переменных всего переставить:)

```
 <?php
 function jencoder($json_str) {
     $cyr_chars = array (
         '\u0430' => 'а', '\u0410' => 'А',
         '\u0431' => 'б', '\u0411' => 'Б',
         '\u0432' => 'в', '\u0412' => 'В',
         '\u0433' => 'г', '\u0413' => 'Г',
         '\u0434' => 'д', '\u0414' => 'Д',
         '\u0435' => 'е', '\u0415' => 'Е',
         '\u0451' => 'ё', '\u0401' => 'Ё',
         '\u0436' => 'ж', '\u0416' => 'Ж',
         '\u0437' => 'з', '\u0417' => 'З',
         '\u0438' => 'и', '\u0418' => 'И',
         '\u0439' => 'й', '\u0419' => 'Й',
         '\u043a' => 'к', '\u041a' => 'К',
         '\u043b' => 'л', '\u041b' => 'Л',
         '\u043c' => 'м', '\u041c' => 'М',
         '\u043d' => 'н', '\u041d' => 'Н',
         '\u043e' => 'о', '\u041e' => 'О',
         '\u043f' => 'п', '\u041f' => 'П',
         '\u0440' => 'р', '\u0420' => 'Р',
         '\u0441' => 'с', '\u0421' => 'С',
         '\u0442' => 'т', '\u0422' => 'Т',
         '\u0443' => 'у', '\u0423' => 'У',
         '\u0444' => 'ф', '\u0424' => 'Ф',
         '\u0445' => 'х', '\u0425' => 'Х',
         '\u0446' => 'ц', '\u0426' => 'Ц',
         '\u0447' => 'ч', '\u0427' => 'Ч',
         '\u0448' => 'ш', '\u0428' => 'Ш',
         '\u0449' => 'щ', '\u0429' => 'Щ',
         '\u044a' => 'ъ', '\u042a' => 'Ъ',
         '\u044b' => 'ы', '\u042b' => 'Ы',
         '\u044c' => 'ь', '\u042c' => 'Ь',
         '\u044d' => 'э', '\u042d' => 'Э',
         '\u044e' => 'ю', '\u042e' => 'Ю',
         '\u044f' => 'я', '\u042f' => 'Я',

         '\r' => '',
         '\n' => '<br />',
         '\t' => ''
     );

     foreach ($cyr_chars as $key => $value) {
         $json_str = str_replace($value, $key, $json_str);
     }
     return $json_str;
 }

echo jencoder("Скачать"); 
?>
```