# unicode to decimal in php

Tags: php

Ребята, подскажите как конвертировать unicode в decimal?

Мне нужно из `\ud83d\ude05` получить `&#128517;`

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function uniord($ch) {

$n = ord($ch{0});

 if ($n < 128) { 
     return $n; // no conversion required 
 }

 if ($n < 192 || $n > 253) { 
     return false; // bad first byte || out of range 
 }

 $arr = array(1 => 192, // byte position => range from 
              2 => 224, 
              3 => 240, 
              4 => 248, 
              5 => 252, 
              );

 foreach ($arr as $key => $val) { 
     if ($n >= $val) { // add byte to the 'char' array 
         $char[] = ord($ch{$key}) - 128; 
         $range  = $val; 
     } else { 
         break; // save some e-trees 
     } 
 }

 $retval = ($n - $range) * pow(64, sizeof($char));

 foreach ($char as $key => $val) { 
     $pow = sizeof($char) - ($key + 1); // invert key 
     $retval += $val * pow(64, $pow);   // dark magic 
 }

 return $retval; 
}
$decimal = '&#' . uniord(json_decode('"\ud83d\ude05"')) . ';';
echo $decimal;
?>
```

https://ideone.com/UYUD9i

Функцию uniord взял [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26399/php-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5).