# string (all) to html special characters

Tags: php

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как мне c помощью php конвертировать строку в 10ю кодировку и по надобности обратно ?

я имею ввиду вот как сдесь http://easywebscripts.net/html/spec_char.php

понаходил функции только которые кавычки и угловые скобки преобразуют, а буквы латинские и русские - нет. 
Спасибо.

Comment: не открывается ваша ссылка. Приведите пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @rjhdby все вроде нормально открыв http://joxi.ru/Dr8Poj1iBYxDr6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая [функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26399/php-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) `uniord` возвращает десятичный код unicode-символа, а [функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php#107658) `str_split_unicode` разбивает unicode-строку на массив символов.

Проходим циклом по символам и кодируем их в нужный формат. Получить обратно строку можно с помощью [метода](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) `html_entity_decode`.

```
<?php
function uniord($ch)
{

$n = ord($ch{0});

if ($n < 128) {
    return $n; // no conversion required 
}

if ($n < 192 || $n > 253) {
    return false; // bad first byte || out of range 
}

$arr = array(
    1 => 192, // byte position => range from 
    2 => 224,
    3 => 240,
    4 => 248,
    5 => 252
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($n >= $val) { // add byte to the 'char' array 
        $char[] = ord($ch{$key}) - 128;
        $range  = $val;
    } else {
        break; // save some e-trees 
    }
}

$retval = ($n - $range) * pow(64, sizeof($char));

foreach ($char as $key => $val) {
    $pow = sizeof($char) - ($key + 1); // invert key 
    $retval += $val * pow(64, $pow); // dark magic 
}

return $retval;
}

function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0)
{
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

$str = 'Привет, world!';
$new_str = '';
foreach (str_split_unicode($str) as $ch)
    $new_str .= '&#' . uniord($ch) . ';';

echo $new_str . "\n" . html_entity_decode($new_str);
?>
```

Вывод:

```
&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;&#44;&#32;&#119;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;&#33;
Привет, world!
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d34b1c6c2a09ac6269a51eee4857a47b545a38e

Comment: круто! спасибо, вы спасли мой день )))